# Protobuf-net: change name of message

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have to following scenario: today the same message is used for two different operations. The operations started out as very similar but are now becoming different, and so the messages should be differentiated.

So, how do I "split" the messages and maintain retro compatibility? Is it possible?
I mean, today I have

```
[ProtoContract]
class Foo{ ... }
```

Tomorrow I would like to have

```
[ProtoContract]
class Foo{ ... }

[ProtoContract]
class Bar{ /* Identical fields and ProtoMemeber as Foo, at least for now */ }
```

and serialize them as Foo and Bar, but still have the *old* clients deserialize only Foo:

```
var x = Serialize<Bar>(someBar);
//... send x to old client who does not know about Bar
var foo = Deserialize<Foo>(x); // deserialize correctly because fields are identical
```

Is it possible?
Do I need to add some attributes, or do something else?

---

EDIT: It seems to "just work":

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var x = new Foo();
            x.AcquireTimeInLocalTime = DateTime.Now;
            x.Chans[23] = new SomeItem() { SomeString = "Ciao" };
            Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(stream, x, PrefixStyle.Base128);

            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            var y = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<Bar>(stream, PrefixStyle.Base128);
            
            Console.WriteLine($"{y.AcquireTimeInLocalTime}, {y.Chans[23].SomeString}, {y.GetType().Name}");
        }
    }
```

Prints

```
01/12/20 10:43:17, Ciao, Bar
```

Which is what I expected. But I'll leave the question open, as I am not sure this is just incidental or it is expected (and supported) behaviour. I am looking for a more authoritative answer than an experiment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you use something like `google.protobuf.Any` (which includes the message name in the data), you should be fine. The name of the message *isn't* generally part of the data serialized in protocol buffers. (And it could be different between different languages, or in a different package etc.)

I don't know what protobuf-net does with unknown fields, but within Google.Protobuf, the deserialization process will succeed even if there are fields with tag numbers that weren't known about at generation time. (Depending on the version used, the unknown field values may or may not be retained for later serialization. I wouldn't expect protobuf-net to retain values when these are just normal user classes.) This is something you probably want to test, so that if you *do* add any new fields to `Bar` and serialize data using those fields, the `Foo`-only clients are still able to deserialize. (You need to think about the impact of that loss of data though.)

Comment: Thanks Jon. I am using protobuf-net on both sides, and all fields are either primitive types or other [ProtoContract]. We already use addition of tag numbers as a way to expand messages, and it is indeed backward compatible (and forward-compatible, checking on the newer clients for default values). It is worth testing it in this scenario though.

Comment: Just to complete the picture: Adding a field to Bar and deserialize with Foo: OK. Remove a field from Bar and deserialize with Foo: also OK

Comment: Just as a precaution, I will keep the member numeric IDs non-intersecting when adding fields to either of them. It's a bit of a waste but we are over 15 already, so..

Comment: Just to add context on the open question in here: protobuf-net will drop unexpected fields (but still deserialize), unless an API is implemented that is used for storing them. The easiest way to implement that API is to inherit from `ProtoBuf.Extensible` /cc @Lorenzo